# Whenever i perform click operation its navigating to footer instead of moving that page, and test case getting failed.Please give us some solution

Tags: selenium

We have used JS click and normal click but it's moving to the footer.

public static void jsClick(WebDriver driver, WebElement element,String msg) {

```
    try {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
        WaitUtils.staticWait(5000); //3000
        LoggerHelper.log().info(msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LoggerHelper.log().error("Not able to click", e.getCause());
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `element` defined? Relevant text based HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You don't click on a button in Selenium by injecting as JavaScript into it. You should use the Selenium driver in order to click:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.CSS, 'button[id="ButtonID"]')
element.click()
```

In you code example you are not using the Selenium plugin.